# Problem with creating new react native app using expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

i'm trying to create new react native project with expo
so i'm using the command : expo init projectname
choosing blank project.
then i get this problem: × Something when wrong installing JavaScript dependencies. Check your npm logs. Continuing to initialize the app.

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZR3q.png)

npm start wont work after this

Comment: Maybe you should check the npm logs inside your project...

Comment: Do you have the last NODE LTS?

Comment: yes im using 12.16.3

Comment: npm install -g expo-cli and try again

Comment: tried , not working

Comment: Anybody got a solution for this?